# Selling Prototypes To Clients & The FCC

Tags: prototyping

I have a prototype of an electronics product that is still in development. I know that if I were to sell my product that I would have to have it FCC tested before I could sell it. The thing is the product is still in development and I want to ensure product market fit before I run these in mass. I am also wanting to cash flow this project and being able to sell prototype devices or the "service of a prototype device to clients" will help me get the project off the ground without seeking investment before I need to.

I was wondering if any of you had done a similar thing and were able to sell your prototypes or the service of your prototypes to clients without the FCC testing, because your device was in prototype phase.

Comment: You haven't even said whether your device is a intentional radiator or not.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I guess that's helpful if he or I knew all of the requirements, but...

Comment: There is a large difference in the law between intentional and unintentional radiators.  This is the first thing you need to know, although it's hard to imagine how you don't already.

Answer (score 2):

You state: "I would have to have it FCC tested before I could sell it." so I will take that as fact.

Then you go on to say "wanting to cash flow this project and being able to sell prototype devices" which ***seems*** like you want to circumvent the FCC rules in some way.

The biggest issue is trying to charge for your prototype. Of course people and companies build and test prototypes all the time. Further there is no problem demonstrating them to 3 parties etc. If your product will radiate RF energy that could potentially interfere with other devices then the responsible way to develop and test it is inside of a [Faraday cage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) (basically a room with copper sheets on all surfaces that prevents RF from passing in or out. You could even loan it to a 3rd party for them to test inside their own Faraday cage.

Where you are going to get into big trouble (and face severe monetary and criminal penalties) is if you operate an unlicensed device that causes harmful interference to licensed operators, weather intentional or not. For example suppose because of a "bug" in your prototype it inadvertently radiated on a frequency used by aircraft and caused a 747 to crash....

Further this is something probably not covered by your insurance since it is most likely an illegal activity. . .

Bottom line - re-think your plan.

Comment: Another example is if you accidentally radiate on a band that cause cell phones to stop working. If it is just you testing then maybe it will just cause you and your employees to have issues with your phone. Now you go sell it to others and their phones stop working, now you might be having a carrier coming after you for issues that could have been kept in house.

Comment: @Kellenjb, Or more likely you have the FCC coming after you.

Comment: Well, probably carrier telling the FCC to come after you.